# Https POST/GET not working on Mono

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, raspberry-pi, restsharp

I want to execute a HttpPost on a Raspberry using Mono + Restsharp.

The [Httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie) call that i try to reproduce in code looks something like this:

```
 http POST https://XXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/report key=value
```

This is the C# code:

```
RestClient nodeRed = new RestClient("http://XXXXX.azurewebsites.net/");
var request = new RestRequest("api/report", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new { Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Data = "Test" });
request.Timeout = 5000;

var response = nodeRed.Execute(request);
```

The code runs fine, it is just not working. The Response does not contain any content (server response with "Success" on httpie / MS .NET Framework).

I already found out about the Certificate stuff on Mono. Running

```
sudo certmgr -ssl -v -m "https://XXXXX.azurewebsites.net"
```

Tells me it Adds two certificates on the first time. Running it again does add the first Certificate again (and again) like it is not working.

> X.509 Certificate v3
>      Issued from: C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
>      Issued to:   C=US, S=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
>      Valid from:  19/12/2013 20:07:32
>      Valid until: 19/12/2017 20:06:55
>      **WARNING: Certificate signature is INVALID**
>   Import this certificate into the CA store ?

If i confirm and repeat the import, certmgr asks me to import again. How can i get the http post to work?

Comment: I think you have to add certificate to your device: [Mono Certificate Manager >> certmgr ](http://linux.die.net/man/1/certmgr)

Comment: looks like it is missing a certificate

Comment: my workaround has helped you ?

Comment: @gmetax no sadly this seems to have no effekt

Comment: maybe your problem is for raspberry, try to reinstall ca-certificate with --fix-missing

Comment: @Console how it worked an you approved my answer? what was the problem?

Comment: @gmetax if i would know why stuff works now i would tell you :D. I had some other project meanwhile. Now i came back and played around a bit and everything seems to work now

Comment: ok, happy to help you then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to ignore certificates with that

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;
```

**Update** 
as I can see [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/ServicePointManager.cs) exists on Mono also

Answer (score 1):

It must have some connection to Mono By default not trusting any ssl certificate...
well check thess article out http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/  https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/728
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7422

or
You need to use openssl for analyzing the certificate:

```
    openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.domain.com:443
openssl x509 -text -noout -in some.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend i have a line of code which is working for other Place is working fine. You may try this :

**[Request and response web form using Post Method in same page c# asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343374/request-and-response-web-form-using-post-method-in-same-page-c-sharp-asp-net/38370270#38370270)**

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the mono certificate storage i am struggling, and if you think that another Question SO answers a Question, you should mark the question as duplicate instead of posting a link.